# Azure resource group creation using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, region

I am trying to create the resource group in `West India` region in azure using the following terraform code.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "tf_rg" {
  name     = "terraform_resource_group"
  location = "West India"
}
```

It is giving some strange error like below

```
Error: "westindia" was not found in the list of supported Azure Locations: "westus,westus2,eastus,centralus,centraluseuap,southcentralus,northcentralus,westcentralus,eastus2,eastus2euap,brazilsouth,brazilus,northeurope,westeurope,eastasia,southeastasia,japanwest,japaneast,koreacentral,koreasouth,indiasouth,indiawest,indiacentral,australiaeast,australiasoutheast,canadacentral,canadaeast,uksouth,ukwest,francecentral,francesouth,australiacentral,australiacentral2,uaecentral,uaenorth,southafricanorth,southafricawest,switzerlandnorth,switzerlandwest,germanynorth,germanywestcentral,norwayeast,norwaywest,brazilsoutheast"
```

I've also tried changing the region name as `India West`, `westindia` and `indiawest`. But nothing worked, it is giving same kind of error.

I've tried creating resource group in `Centra US` region, Surprisingly it is working. Can anyone let me know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Bug in the `azurerm` provider version `2.20.0`.

I've not faced such issue when I used `2.19.0` version

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.19.0"
  features {}
}
```